# Siege not cycling through URL list

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, load-balancing, siege

I'm using Siege to act as a cache warmer for Varnish on a wordpress site. I've set up a simple script to grab the latest URL list from a dynamic sitemap, output them to a file, purge the cache using Varnishadm and then run siege against the url list to repopulate the cache.

The problem is the Siege part of the equation. If I run the following command:

```
/usr/bin/siege -c1000 -d3 -r1 -v -i -f url-list-example.txt
```

It works fine but this obviously randomly accesses the URL list rather than hit one after another. From what I've read removing the -i flag so that the command is:

```
/usr/bin/siege -c1000 -d3 -r1 -v -f url-list-dekanta.txt
```

should mean that Siege runs through the list once and stops however it doesn't do this. Instead it just hits the first URL which is / multiple times and stops.

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong with this command please? I've read through the docs and nothing seems to work the way I want it to. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Seems I was over complicating things but thanks to Sjon for helping me revisit what I had previously tried and thought failed with.

To cycle through a URL list Siege doesn't need the -d or -c flags as these are specified for mimicking random user behavior (-c for how many users to mimic -d for the wait time before hits). Removing these flags and just running the simple command:

```
/usr/bin/siege --reps=once -v -f url-list-example.txt
```

..resulted in Siege cycling through the list as its supposed to with a default of 15 concurrent users. You can add -c100 or whatever if you want to increase this concurrent amount.

Answer (score 2):

The man page of siege mentions this explicitly as `--reps=once`; and the source [implements that](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/blob/6d81f8c5195c00479d81908940d579b67aed217a/src/main.c#L245) [exception](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/blob/6d81f8c5195c00479d81908940d579b67aed217a/src/main.c#L460). So it seems using `--reps=once` instead of -r1 might fix this for you

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'd tried that last night shortly before giving up for sleep. Running the following results in Siege doing nothing: 

Transactions:             0 hits
Availability:          0.00 %
Elapsed time:          0.46 secs
Data transferred:         0.00 MB
Response time:          0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         0.00 trans/sec
Throughput:          0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:          0.00
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:            0
Longest transaction:         0.00
Shortest transaction:         0.00
FILE: /root/siege.log

Comment: Sorry command that produces no result is - /usr/bin/siege -c1000 -d3 --reps=once -v -f url-list-example.txt